# Python Scrapy giving Import Error on Linux for Extension

Tags: python, scrapy

I am running Scrapy tool from Linux platform. But I am getting 
ImportError: Error loading object 'tellercoins.extensions.SpiderDetails': cannot import name crawler. Here "tellercoins.extensions.SpiderDetails" is my Extension which I have declared in my Settings.py file. Then why this Error? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

This might help, http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/faq.html#i-m-getting-an-error-cannot-import-name-crawler

Basically you need to update the extension as mentioned in the above FAQ page.

P.S. If it still doesn't fix your error please provide the complete error message and code where the error originates( In this case the extension file).